# Source for Arizal Marital Advice

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage, repentance-teshuvah

Rav Ezriel Tauber's [To Become One](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/187899901X) (p.46) quotes a story about the Arizal who told a husband, "This is your tikun, the way you can repair a fault in your spiritual self. In a previous existence the situation was reversed: you were the bad one." The husband changed his entire outlook and smiled every time his wife tried to annoy him. After a few days, he returned to the Arizal who told him that the tikun was fulfilled and his wife's changed behavior for the better is what Hashem planned.

Where is the oldest source of this Arizal?